# variable inside devise.en.yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email, devise

I want to add user's email address in devise confirmation message, right now after a confirmation mail is send, devise shows me **"A message with a confirmation link has been sent to your email address. Please open the link to activate your account."** but what i want is to insert signed up user's email so it should be something like **"A message with a confirmation link has been sent to your #{params[:user][:email]}. Please open the link to activate your account."**

But instead of showing email it simply shows text. Any suggestions how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this issue today so thought should post an answer for others too. Had to override devise registrations controller create action with this code:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController 
  # POST /resource
  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)
    if resource.save
      # this block will be used when user is saved in database
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        # this block will be used when user is active or not required to be confirmed
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        # this block will be used when user is required to be confirmed
        user_flash_msg if is_navigational_format? #created a custom method to set flash message
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      # this block is used when validation fails
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end

  private

  # set custom flash message for unconfirmed user
  def user_flash_msg
    if resource.inactive_message == :unconfirmed
      #check for inactive_message and pass email variable to devise locals message
      set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_unconfirmed", email: resource.email
    else
      set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"
    end
  end
end
```

Then make neccessary changes in devise.en.yml file and we are all set

```
en:
  devise:
    registrations:
      signed_up_but_unconfirmed: "A confirmation link has been sent to %{email}. Click the link to activate your account."
```

P.S Check comments for what's happening

Answer (score 0):

The Rails Guide for i18n covers this case : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#passing-variables-to-translations

In the view :

```
# app/views/home/index.html.erb
<%=t 'greet_username', user: "Bill", message: "Goodbye" %>
```

In the locale file:

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  greet_username: "%{message}, %{user}!"
```

UPDATE :

```
# app/views/home/index.html.erb
<%=t 'email_message', email: params[:user][:email] %>

# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  email_message: "Your email address is : %{email}"
```

Comment: can you be a little more specific on how to put user's email in devise.en.yml..when a user click's on sign up, i can get his/her email by params[:user][:email] and i tried %{params[:user][:email]} inside error message but it simply gave me the text and not the user's email

Comment: See the UPDATE above.

Comment: i need to set it from controller not view

Comment: Sorry but i'm still learning and actually that's the problem, i'm using devise and i just can't find from where its calling the function to send mail, thats why instead of declaring a variable i tried using %{[:user][:emai]} directly in devise.en.yml file